# Salesforce backup on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, salesforce

I am doing a POC for a backup solution for salesforce objects on AWS. I am familiar with AWS but know very little about salesforce. I am thinking of using DynamoDB to backup all the tables and store schema on s3. Is this a good solution? Or are there any other services which might be better suited for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are wanting to do is backup the salesforce data, as opposed to keeping a copy for some other purpose, then Dynamodb seems like a poor solution to the problem as you presented it.

Salesforce has the ability to export data to csv/zip files. If it was me I would just automated the upload(s) of those exports to S3, and then possibly have lifecycle rules to then move those backups to glacier for even cheaper/long-term storage.

If you ever need the backups, you would have the ability to retrieve them and then convert them back to a database format and/or reload to salesforce (if that is supported - I am not a salesfoce expert) - dynamodb as a backup option seems like way more work, expense and complication - with no upside benefit.

Comment: It will be a full backup and restore solution. I imagine it'll need to handle a scenario where it compares 2 backups to get back missing values. I was initially considering simply dumping the csv and schema on s3 as well, but then idk what to do if I ever have to compare the data.